# I write a style for a subscribe form. It's looks good in firefox. But style is not looking similar in opera. How to fix it?

Tags: html, css, firefox, opera

## My code is working in Firefox but not looking good in Opera.

> the height of input/text and input/submit is similar in firefox but in opera the input/submit height is reduced.

### this is html code

```
<footer>
<div class="subsceibe">
    <h3>Get Notefied</h3>
    <br>
    <form method="post">
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter E-Mail"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe">
    </form>
  </div>
  </footer>
```

### this is css code

```
footer .subsceibe form input { border: 1px solid; padding: 6px 10px; outline: none; }

footer .subsceibe form input:last-child { color: #001001; background: #00A240; border: 1px solid #00A240; padding: 5px 10px; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold; }

footer .subsceibe form input:last-child:hover { color: #00A240; background: #001001; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KjzROe)

```
 .input {
     height: 28px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

Give specific height for both the input.
I added above properties and found its appearing same in both browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `height` parameter to the css.

For example: `height: 20px; line-height: 20px;`